# Finding the latitude and longitude from an address

Tags: android, dictionary, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to display markers on map in android by using address.
This is my code:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
    mMap = googleMap;
    Geocoder coder= new Geocoder(this);
    try
    {
        String straddress = "155 Park Theater,Palo Alto,CA";
        Double latitude = 0.0;
        Double longitude = 0.0;
        List<Address> addresses = coder.getFromLocationName("155 Park Theater,Palo Alto,CA",1);
        Address location = addresses.get(0);
        LatLng p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(p1).title("California"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(p1));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If I do not put street number, then it will display the marker. 
But, it will just display marker on the street. I want marker on particular location.

I am getting following error while inputting the whole address with street number. The "address" list is empty.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with following :

```
 List<Address> address;
 LatLng latLng = null;

try {
    address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
    if (address==null) {
       return null;
    }
    Address location=address.get(0);
    latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    }
```